# How to use xtick.major.width and xtick.minor.widtch rcParams keys?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to using matplotlib. I noticed that in matplotlib, there are the following keys [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/rcsetup.py#L1316)

```
'xtick.major.width': [0.8, validate_float],  # major xtick width in points
'xtick.minor.width': [0.6, validate_float],  # minor xtick width in points
```

I'm looking at examples to change tick properties.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                               AutoMinorLocator)


t = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t) * np.exp(-t * 0.01)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())

ax.tick_params(which='major', width=2)
```

This example was taken from [here:](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/major_minor_demo.html) (I changed it so that it customizes the major ticks width to 2, instead of both)

This changes the width of the major ticks programmatically. Is there a way to change it using the keys from rcParams? (i.e., using `xtick.major.width` and `xtick.minor.width`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you have several options, if you want to apply the change only for the current script (or current iPython kernel if you are running one) you can do

```py
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 2
```

If you want it to persist across scripts or iPython kernels you need to change your matplotlibrc file, the location of which can be retrieved via

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

You would then need to append

```
xtick.major.width : 2
```

to the file. For more detail on customizing via `rcParams` see [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html).